# Pihole still making DHCP leases for hosts which have a static DHCP lease

Tags: dhcp

I have some hosts on my network that I want to always have the same IP address therefore I set them up under the static DHCP lease section within the pihole configuration.

I then delete the existing lease that host has, and then restart the host. Upon booting up, the pihole leased out the original IP address and not the statically assigned IP address.

How can I force pihole to give it the IP address I want it to have?

Comment: How are you setting the static IP configuration? More importantly, is your static IP in the **Range of IP Addresses to hand out** within DHCP Settings of Pihole? It should be if you are reserving the IP address in Pihole's DHCP settings. It should **not** be if you are setting static IP address in the Pi's `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file using the `static ip_address=" option.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the existing lease, then on the host on your network make sure you are clearing the lease.  For example, on archlinux, I did the command

dhcpcd -k

which releases the IP, then when I run dhcpcd again, it takes the static dhcp lease configured on the pihole.

Worked for me... hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the web interface then you NEED to click SAVE button after you click delete lease.  Otherwise it will not save the fact that you tried to delete the dynamic lease.

Also as noted by another reply.  The if you are using the web interface Static IP address you are using should be within the range you have set for the DHCP.